# Is there an alternative to git-annex for windows?

Tags: backup, file-management, git-annex

see http://git-annex.branchable.com/
Especially the use case of the archivist. Reproduced below

> use case: The Archivist
>
> Bob has many drives to archive his data, most of them kept offline, in
>   a safe place.
>
> With git-annex, Bob has a single directory tree that includes all his
>   files, even if their content is being stored offline. He can
>   reorganize his files using that tree, committing new versions to git,
>   without worry about accidentally deleting anything.
>
> When Bob needs access to some files, git-annex can tell him which
>   drive(s) they're on, and easily make them available. Indeed, every
>   drive knows what is on every other drive. more about location tracking
>
> Bob thinks long-term, and so he appreciates that git-annex uses a
>   simple repository format. He knows his files will be accessible in the
>   future even if the world has forgotten about git-annex and git. more
>   about future-proofing
>
> Run in a cron job, git-annex adds new files to archival drives at
>   night. It also helps Bob keep track of intentional, and unintentional
>   copies of files, and logs information he can use to decide when it's
>   time to duplicate the content of old drives. more about backup copies

Essentially that's what I do with some photo files. Being paranoid, i maintain several copies and keep originals seperate from display use. I think git-annex would help solve this problem, but since I use windows what can I do to make management easier?

Currently I use FreeFileSync manually to keep things in the archive.

Comment: "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." How could it be better described than in the provided snippet?

Comment: I feel the same @Alicia but unfortunately it seems like there's no readymade solution for this. Have to kludge one up, in case you stumbled here with the same question.

Comment: git-annex beta runs on Windows
http://git-annex.branchable.com/todo/windows_support/
Also git-annex runs in WSL under Windows 10 without any of the limitation of the beta Windows port.